# Browsers don't remember values of input fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have this code:

```
      = simple_form_for :entry, url: '/check', method: :get, remote: true do |f|
        .row
          .col-sm-4.col-sm-offset-4.col-xs-11
            = f.input :email_or_code, input_html: { class: 'input-lg form-control has_tooltip text-center'}, label: false, placeholder: 'Epost eller kodeord', id: 'entry_input'
            %hr.visible-xs

        .row.visible-xs 

          .col-xs-11.text-center
            = f.submit 'Go!', class: 'btn btn-lg', id: 'commit'
```

In this input, you can either write your email or a code ("happy rabbit"). 
But whatever I write in this field, it's never remembered for next time. There's no dropdown menu of previously inputted emails or codes.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But whatever I write in this field, it's never remembered for next time. There's no dropdown menu of previously inputted emails or codes.

That's because the form is `remote` and the values are submitted outside of the form (via Ajax) and reach of the web browser, thus it cannot save them. From its point of view, the form hasn't been submitted.

Comment: @NadeemJ.Q. Well, I don't think you can make the browser to remember the inputs via any API but you could fetch the history from the server when the user focuses the input field and display it via some JS widget. Of course this would require you to save the values per user on the server whenever the he/she submits the remote form.

Comment: Hmm. OK.

I've seen many sites using AJAX for login, and the values are remembered. How do they do it?

Comment: @NadeemJ.Q. Could you give some examples? We can take a look, on the client side at least.

Comment: Can't remember any off the bat, but will let you know when I stumble upon one :)

Perhaps I could use cookies and sessions?